# 4 options for a CSS Selector. None of them work for me

Tags: html, css

I have been given the following multiple choice question:

> 13. Which CSS selector applies to all div tags within the ID called “red”:
>
> A. red blue
>
> B. div #red
>
> C. red div
>
> D. $red div

I was not sure which one worked, so first I did some Googling, and read the relevant articles on W3Schools, but I still couldn't see an example using any of the styles listed above.

So I tried writing up an html document with a CCS style element in the header, and tried all 4 of the given answers. However none of them seem to work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        red blue {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="red">
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code for A. gave no border. When line 5 was changed to `div #red {`, then `red div {`, then `$red div`, there was still no border shown.

Am I being stupid? Or is there a typo? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `E. #red div` has to be the answer.

Comment: Wrong `Which CSS selector applies to all div tags within the ID called “red”`. My selector is correct.

Comment: @Huelfe - sorry, my bad. Skimmed through it and read "with ID called red" not within

Comment: @Huelfe actually `div#red` is probably the more correct intended choice

Comment: The simple answer to the question is NONE of them. A correct answer could be `#red div`

Comment: @TylerH but `div#red` is definitely wrong.

Comment: On a US keyboard layout, $ is shift-4 and # is shift-3. So I'd go with a typo in choice D.

Comment: @Huelfe Actually either the test makers are definitely wrong or OP has incorrectly transcribed the options.

Comment: It is correctly transcribed, I triple checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the B) option is div (space) #red? Because the correct answer is div#red (note, no space). So if the B) option is "div (space) #red" then there's a typo in the answers, yes

EDIT: My bad, I read the question as "with the ID called red", not "within the ID red". In that case, the proper answer is "#red div"